# how to convert audio x-wav file to regular wav file

Tags: audio, wav

I have a few audio files without file extension tag. it can be detected with the following info:

> File Type: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, mono 16000 Hz
>   MIME Type: audio/x-wav

I wonder how I can convert them to regular wave files.

Answer (score 3):

audio/x-wav is the **MIME Type**. A **MIME Type** is just an identifier for file formats transmitted on the Internet. Most probably the audio is a PCM uncompressed audio and it is already in a wave container (***.wav**)